# How to copy part of a collection from a remote server to a local database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, so I'm probably just missing something simple. A remote server has a MongoDB database called `DatabaseABC` which has a collection called `Logger`. This collection is humongous. I figured the best way to understand how to query against it without having to wait several minutes between queries was to copy the last day's worth of documents in the collection locally.

From what I've read, I should be able to use [cloneCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) and give it a query to filter it down. I can't get it to work. The documentation says,

> You must connect directly to the mongod instance.

but I don't understand what that means. How do I connect to a local database using `mongod`? `mongod` seems like a way to start a database, I can do that, but I don't get how to run `{ cloneCollection: "DatabaseABC.Logger", from: "mongoDevEtc.domain.net:27017", query: { TheTimestamp: "2015-05-13" } }` with it.

I need baby steps. Assume I have a local database called `test`. I have a fresh Microsoft Windows command prompt open pointed at the bin directory where mongod.exe exists. What commands do I enter in order to move all the logs written on May 13, 2015 from `mongoDevEtc.domain.net:27017.DatabaseABC.Logger` to my local collection at `127.0.0.1:21000.test.Logger` (note, the logger collection doesn't exist locally yet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `mongod` is the MongoDB server. It understands a bunch of different [commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/), but you need to use a *client* to issue those commands. The standard client for MongoDB is [the Mongo Shell called `mongo`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/). You can invoke it directly from the command line and start issuing some commands.

Now, for your specific needs: the [`cloneCollection` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) allows you to copy from one collection in a DB on a *distant* server to an other collection, on a different DB on you *local* server (i.e.: the one to which your client is connected). From the Mongo Shell, you may issue this command (like any other "raw" command) using [`db.runCommand`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/). Something like that:

```
> db.runCommand(
               { cloneCollection: "DatabaseABC.Logger",
                 from: "mongoDevEtc.domain.net:27017",
                 query: { TheTimestamp: "2015-05-13" }
               }
)
```

---

Please note that is your distant db has the same name as your local db you might use the Mongo Shell database method [`db.cloneCollection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/) instead:

```
> db.cloneCollection("mongoDevEtc.domain.net:27017",
                     "Logger",
                     { TheTimestamp: "2015-05-13" })¶
```

As you can see below, `db.cloneCollection` is a simple wrapper around the `cloneCollection` database command:

```
> db.cloneCollection
function (from, collection, query) {
    assert( isString(from) && from.length );
    assert( isString(collection) && collection.length );
    collection = this._name + "." + collection;
    query = query || {};
    return this._dbCommand( { cloneCollection:collection, from:from, query:query } );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this as soon as I can and likely mark this as the answer. I'm a little confused, though. If I use "mongo" doesn't that use the shell? My concern is this line in the documentation, "db.cloneCollection() does not allow you to clone a collection through a mongos. You must connect directly to the mongod instance."

Answer (score 0):

To copy a database from a machine to your machine, fallow this steps:

1. Open the cmd
2. Run this code to copy:

   ```
   mongodump  --db Your_database_name /h IP_of_remote_machine
   ```

   ex:

   ```
   mongodump  --db myDb /h 192.168.0.100
   ```
3. Run to restore the database from dump/myNpsCorporate  to mongodb:

   ```
   mongorestore  --Your_database_name dump/Your_database_name
   ```

   ex:

   ```
   mongorestore  --myDb dump/myDb
   ```
4. finish

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's an interesting way to backup and restore a database.